# Windows server starts in System Recovery Options

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

Wher restarting a Windows Server 2008R2, shutdown tracker asked me to choose the reason, and I (by mistake) selected an Operating System recovery, or something like that, and when it rebooted, it took me to System Recovery Options and I can't get out of it, on every reboot it takes me there. I thought Shutddown tracker was only for documenting purposes and I didn't pay attention to it, but it seems it actually altered the way system starts up now.

Comment: When you restart the system try to hitting the del or F8 key to choose the booting option.

Comment: This might be better on ServerFault.  Voting to migrate so do not post there as well.

Comment: I tried F8, but the same happens in every case, safe mode, last known good config, etc, no matter what I choose, this thing forces me into recovery options

Comment: @fremmedehenvendelser May be a worth to update the boot-loader using [this tutorial](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/bios-booting/ht/bootsect-nt60.htm). If it doesn't work, backup your files using command prompt or UBUNTU disk and then reinstall the OS seems the fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use BCDEDIT to change the default option from the recovery to the normal boot.

```
BCDEDIT /enum
```

to list the entries, and

```
BCDEDIT /default {guid}
```

to set the new default startup.  You must have a timeout value to be presented with the options, however.

You could also try hitting F8 and then choosing "last known good" configuration.

Comment: The last known good takes me to Recovery Options as well, and that's very strange. The problem is, system has no problem at all, it only thinks that I want this Recovery Mode, because I selected it as a reason of shutting down the system.

Comment: @fremmedehenvendelser - selecting a reason for a previous shutdown does not make that "reason" the boot option. You will need to look deeper to find out why it's going in recovery mode.